# Changing SELECT options in Vue component

Tags: jquery, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using a Vue 2 component to implement a jQuery Chosen SELECT field. It's working OK, except that I need to be able to dynamically change the options list and it's not working as expected.

This [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do0vsh64/1/) shows the problem. When you click the button to change the options, nothing changes immediately - however, when you then go on to select an option, then the change occurs.

What do I need to do to make the options list change immediately when the button is clicked?

Here is the JS code:

```
Vue.component("chosen-select",{
    props:{
    value: [String, Array],
    multiple: Boolean
  },
  template:`<select :multiple="multiple"><slot></slot></select>`,
  mounted(){
        $(this.$el)
        .val(this.value)
        .chosen()
      .on("change", e => this.$emit('input', $(this.$el).val()))
    },
  watch:{
    value(val){
       $(this.$el).val(val).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
  }
})

var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    selectedCities: [],
    cities: ["Toronto", "Orleans", "Denver"]
  },
  methods:{
    changeOptions() {
      console.log("changing options");
      this.cities = ["London", "Newcastle", "Liverpool"];
    }
  }
}).$mount("#search-results");
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the key-changing trick described [here](https://michaelnthiessen.com/key-changing-technique/).

Doesn't work too well in the fiddle, where it creates duplicate component - but it does work in my actual application, possibly because there I am using a separate component definition in a .vue file.